# How to ask someone to speak lower and louder?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Which sentences are the correct to ask someone to speak using a lower voice or  a louder voice?

> - Can you please speak **lower**?
> - Can you please speak **louder** ?
> - Can you please **low** your voice?
> - Can you please **loud** your voice ?

Comment: Note that "lower" could mean more quietly (less loud) or it could mean with a lower pitch (deeper sound). It's not clear from your question which one you mean.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I immediately read "lower" as "deeper pitch".  It wasn't until I read the answer I realized it could also mean "more quietly".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maryam's comment pretty much covers it, although I'll add a few more examples:

> Can you speak **louder**?
>   Can you **raise** your voice?
>   Can you speak **up**?
>   Can you speak **more loudly**?
>
> Can you speak **softer**?
>   Can you **lower** your voice?
>   Can you speak **more quietly**?

Feel free to add "please", and/or "Could you ..." to make it more polite.  You can also say "Would you ..." to make it more of a demand:

> **Would you please** lower your voice in the library?  Thank you.

Note:  I don't know why you can say, "Could you speak *up*?" but you can't say, "Could you speak *down*?"  It's just one of those strange English quirks.

Answer (score 4):

It is more natural to use the adjective / adverb:

> Would you speak **louder**. please?

or

> Would you speak a little **louder**, please?
>
> Would you speak (more) **quietly**. please?
>
> could you speak a bit **softer**?

And if someone around you speaking or playing loudly, then you can say something like:

> "Would you tone it down a bit, please."

---

As for

> Can you please speak **lower**?

It may imply that the person should speak while being in a lower position.

But you can say:

> Could you **lower your voice**?

Comment: "Can you please speak lower?" doesn't necessarily imply that someone should speak from a lower position. I would interpret that question as asking the person to lower or deepen the pitch of their voice.

Comment: I rewrited the sentence: "It may imply..."